# How can I implement an outlook-like calendar in ASP.NET that chooses a start and end date in one control?

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

I have a page where I am trying to mimic some of outlook's calendar functionality. I'd like to have a calendar control where the user can click a start and end date, maybe even by clicking-and-dragging. I like the single control because it feels like it will look better and the user will feel a little more comfortable selecting dates. I don't necessarily need to pick multiple individual, non-consecutive dates... just a start and end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik Rad Calendar

Comment: I feel like I can do this without buying something, but since no one else chimed in, I'll award you with the answer.